# Como guardar las respuestas parciales de una función recursiva?

Tags: c++, recursión

tengo este código de una función recursiva en c++. Quisiera saber como se puede almacenar los resultados parciales en un arreglo?

```
int FACTORIAL (int numero)     
{
    int resultado;

    if (numero > 0)
    {
        resultado = numero * FACTORIAL (numero-1);
    }
    else if (numero < 0)
    {
        return 0;  
    }
    else
    {
        resultado = 1;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe una variedad de opciones. Será mejor que pienses un poco y elijas la más adecuada para tus propósitos.

Por ejemplo, puedes recibir un arreglo como parámetro (suponiendo que tenga la capacidad suficiente):

```
int FACTORIAL (int numero, int* resultados)     
{
    int resultado;

    if (numero > 0)
    {
        resultado = numero * FACTORIAL (numero-1, resultados);
    }
    else if (numero < 0)
    {
        return 0;  
    }
    else
    {
        resultado = 1;
    }
    resultados[numero] = resultado;

    return resultado;
}

int main(){
    int res[6];
    // Para que un arreglo tenga posición 5 es necesario que tenga al menos 6 elementos.
    // Esto porque se usa el número como posición para guardar los elementos.
    FACTORIAL(5, res);
}
```

O puedes crear un arreglo de un tamaño arbitrario con un ámbito mayor. De esta forma no necesitas pasar el arreglo como parámetro:

```
int resultados[100];

int FACTORIAL(int numero)     
{
    ...

    resultados[numero] = resultado;
    return resultado;
}

int main()
{
    FACTORIAL(5);
}
```

Comment: Ya me funciono, gracias